# Do some apps prohibit mirroring through VGA?

Tags: video

I have an iPad 2, which was running iOS 5.x. I could mirror every app on a TV using a VGA adaptor. I recently upgraded to iOS 8.3 and, unbeknownst to me, the new OS's default settings also updated all my apps. Now I find most apps still mirror, including YouTube, but a couple apps (the kind requiring a monthly fee for streaming video content) no longer mirror video content.

I've looked here and elsewhere to figure out what's going on, but it's confusing. Did the content providers behind the apps change their policies about projectable content recently? Are the apps now providing content at a resolution too high for a VGA connection? ... Most importantly, of course, do I have any options to once again mirror these video outputs to a TV screen?

Comment: iOS is just a slave in this case (it does as told). Check individual app for the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Some Apps (usually those with paid content) prohibit video output via AirPlay or AV-Adapters. There's no way I know of to get around the issue. 
For some, not all, a HDMI adapter works because of "[High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection)"

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. I assume this means the change was relatively recent since I did not have the issue until I updated.

Comment: It has been this way since quite a long time. Like Buscar said, it's not really an OS thing but a decision of the App developer.